# Problem with duplicate emails with different uniqueId

Tags: mailkit

I present the case a little. I have an application that downloads the emails to your computer via Mailkit.Imap. When someone sends an email with attachments, and shortly after someone downloads the email (in a margin of 5-10 seconds) this person receives a kind of "draft" with a uniqueId different from the email that a few seconds later, it ends up being saved in the mail (office365).

Example:

1- I send email with two attachments.
2- 5 seconds later, another person, try to download the mails with this:

```
Dim listIds = ImapCliente.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.SentSince(pdate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)))
    Dim listdoMjs = ImapCliente.Inbox.Fetch(listIds, MessageSummaryItems.Envelope)
```

3-Among those downloaded, appears the email with the attachments, with all the email information BUT without attachments (uniqueid ex=1111)

4-Few seconds later, the mail manager, replace the "draft" mail with a new one with a different uniqueId AND with the attachments (erase uniqueid ex=1111 and create a new uniqueid ex=1112)

5-The person who downloaded the mail with uniqueid 1111 tries to access the attachments, but gives a null error, since the attachments are in uniqueid 1112

Does anyone know how to get only the DEFINITIVE emails from the inbox? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not normal behavior of an IMAP server, so I don't think anyone will be able to answer your question.

There's no way to determine that the message with UID 1111 will be replaced a few seconds later with UID 1112 which will be an identical message, this time containing the attachments that should have existed the entire time.

If that is really the way the server is behaving, then there is a major server bug. It should not be doing that.

Comment: The problem are the flags. when one flag change (unread to read) the UID change. Solved controlling that.